# Mercurial: Removing a single, non-head, changeset

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How do I remove a single changeset (which is not a head) from a repository?

- `hg strip` doesn't work because I don't wanna remove the descendants.
- `hg rebase` on a head and then `hg strip` *would* work, but I can't rebase on a descendent. (that yields an error)

My changeset is not related to anything else (it's just a bunch of file adds I shouldn't have made), so it *should* be easy to remove without problems. Also, my repository in fact has a linear history (each changeset only has one child and in particular, there's only one head).

### Background

I'm using hgsubversion and either it or my SVN server crash when I try to push a commit that touches any file that has umlauts in its name. I accidentally added such a file and then did some other work on top of it. Now the offending commit needs to be removed.

Comment: Does the changeset you want to strip show up in `hg heads`? If so you can just strip it. It doesn't matter that it's not the tip-most commit in the changeset graph if it's still a branch head.

Comment: Yes, it's not a *head*. I made a typo above and fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [ngoldbaum implied in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032826/mercurial-removing-a-single-non-tip-changeset#comment85086230_49032826), strip removes *descendants*, not ancestors.  If there are no descendants you're OK.  (Watch out, though: descendants in another branch *will* be stripped!)

If your issue is that the commit has descendants, you can still use `hg histedit` to remove it while keeping its descendants.

Comment: Wow, `hg histedit` did the job and it's super easy! :) Yes, my commit has *descendants*. I fixed that typo in my question.